# Calculate and create categories age display sum by column

Tags: mysql, sum, case, multiple-columns

Here is my query.
I calculate age, after i sum occurence for each categorie everything right.

```
SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN AGE <18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '<18', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN AGE >= 18 AND AGE <= 24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '18-24', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN AGE >= 25 AND AGE <= 34 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '25-34',
        SUM(CASE WHEN AGE >= 35 AND AGE <= 44 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '35-44', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN AGE >= 45 AND AGE <= 54 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '45-54', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN AGE >= 55 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS '>=55'
    FROM (SELECT t_personne.pers_date_naissance, t_personne.pers_date_inscription, 
            TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year, t_personne.pers_date_naissance, t_personne.pers_date_inscription) - 
            CASE WHEN MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_naissance) > MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_inscription) 
            OR (MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_naissance) = MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_inscription) 
            AND DAY(t_personne.pers_date_naissance) > DAY(t_personne.pers_date_inscription))
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS AGE
            FROM t_personne) AS Total
```

give :

```
<18|18-24|25-34|35-44|45-54|>=55    
67 |693  |1619 |1486 |616  |93
```

But I'd like this:

```
AGE  |Total|
<18  |67   |
18-24|693  |
25-34|1619 |
35-44|1486 |
45-54|616  |
>=55 |93   |
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a cross join with the column name to transpose it

```
SELECT 
    age_range,
    CASE age_range 
        WHEN '<18' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN AGE <18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        WHEN '18-24' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN AGE >= 18 AND AGE <= 24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        WHEN '25-34' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN AGE >= 25 AND AGE <= 34 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        WHEN '35-44' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN AGE >= 35 AND AGE <= 44 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        WHEN '45-54' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN AGE >= 45 AND AGE <= 54 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        WHEN '>=55' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN AGE >= 55 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    END value
FROM 
(   SELECT 
        t_personne.pers_date_naissance, 
        t_personne.pers_date_inscription, 
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year, t_personne.pers_date_naissance, t_personne.pers_date_inscription) 
        - CASE 
            WHEN MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_naissance) > MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_inscription) 
             OR (MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_naissance) = MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_inscription) 
             AND DAY(t_personne.pers_date_naissance) > DAY(t_personne.pers_date_inscription))
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 
          END AS AGE
    FROM t_personne
) AS Total
CROSS JOIN
(   SELECT '<18' age_range UNION ALL
    SELECT '18-24' UNION ALL
    SELECT '25-34' UNION ALL
    SELECT '35-44' UNION ALL
    SELECT '45-54' UNION ALL
    SELECT '>=55'
)a
GROUP BY age_range
ORDER BY FIELD(age_range, '<18', '18-24', '25-34', '35-44', '45-54', '>=55')
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7185/8)

Comment: it works. A big thank you John for leaning on my question. If he has other ways, I'm interested. :)

Comment: @leerickx thanks if it solves your issue could you mark it as accepted? i would be very appreciative

Answer (score -1):

Not so elegant but it will work

```
SELECT
    '<18' as AGE,COUNT(AGE) AS Total FROM
    (SELECT t_personne.pers_date_naissance, t_personne.pers_date_inscription, 
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year, t_personne.pers_date_naissance, t_personne.pers_date_inscription) - 
        CASE WHEN MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_naissance) > MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_inscription) 
        OR (MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_naissance) = MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_inscription) 
        AND DAY(t_personne.pers_date_naissance) > DAY(t_personne.pers_date_inscription))
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS AGE
        FROM t_personne) as Totals where AGE <18
UNION
 SELECT
    '18-24',COUNT(AGE) AS Total FROM
    (SELECT t_personne.pers_date_naissance, t_personne.pers_date_inscription, 
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year, t_personne.pers_date_naissance, t_personne.pers_date_inscription) - 
        CASE WHEN MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_naissance) > MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_inscription) 
        OR (MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_naissance) = MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_inscription) 
        AND DAY(t_personne.pers_date_naissance) > DAY(t_personne.pers_date_inscription))
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS AGE
        FROM t_personne) as Totals where AGE >= 18 AND AGE <= 24 
 UNION
 SELECT
    '25-34',COUNT(AGE) AS Total FROM
    (SELECT t_personne.pers_date_naissance, t_personne.pers_date_inscription, 
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year, t_personne.pers_date_naissance, t_personne.pers_date_inscription) - 
        CASE WHEN MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_naissance) > MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_inscription) 
        OR (MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_naissance) = MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_inscription) 
        AND DAY(t_personne.pers_date_naissance) > DAY(t_personne.pers_date_inscription))
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS AGE
        FROM t_personne) as Totals where AGE >= 25 AND AGE <= 34 
UNION
 SELECT
    '35-44',COUNT(AGE) AS Total FROM
    (SELECT t_personne.pers_date_naissance, t_personne.pers_date_inscription, 
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year, t_personne.pers_date_naissance, t_personne.pers_date_inscription) - 
        CASE WHEN MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_naissance) > MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_inscription) 
        OR (MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_naissance) = MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_inscription) 
        AND DAY(t_personne.pers_date_naissance) > DAY(t_personne.pers_date_inscription))
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS AGE
        FROM t_personne) as Totals where AGE >= 35 AND AGE <= 44
UNION
 SELECT
    '45-54',COUNT(AGE) AS Total FROM
    (SELECT t_personne.pers_date_naissance, t_personne.pers_date_inscription, 
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year, t_personne.pers_date_naissance, t_personne.pers_date_inscription) - 
        CASE WHEN MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_naissance) > MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_inscription) 
        OR (MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_naissance) = MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_inscription) 
        AND DAY(t_personne.pers_date_naissance) > DAY(t_personne.pers_date_inscription))
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS AGE
        FROM t_personne) as Totals where AGE >= 45 AND AGE <= 54
UNION
 SELECT
    '>=55',COUNT(AGE) AS Total FROM
    (SELECT t_personne.pers_date_naissance, t_personne.pers_date_inscription, 
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(Year, t_personne.pers_date_naissance, t_personne.pers_date_inscription) - 
        CASE WHEN MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_naissance) > MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_inscription) 
        OR (MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_naissance) = MONTH(t_personne.pers_date_inscription) 
        AND DAY(t_personne.pers_date_naissance) > DAY(t_personne.pers_date_inscription))
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS AGE
        FROM t_personne) as Totals where AGE >= 55
```

Comment: With a little rearrangement, I think you only need to do that subquery once.

Comment: Almost :) Could not we do lighter? I'll post a sqlfiddle.
<18 Total 
<18 418
18-24 14971
25-34 47941
35-44 58189
>=55 5946